# Python - Properties and Pylint

Tags: python, properties, pylint, python-decorators

Am I doing something un-pythonic here? Or is this a pylint bug?

```
class Thing(object):
    """
    Thing used for stackoverflow example.
    """

    def __init__(self, something):
        """
        Initialize Thing.
        """

        # Set defaults.
        self._something = None

        # Set values using getter/setter methods - this allows for checks.
        self.something = something

    @property
    def something(self):
        """
        Get something
        """
        return self._something

    @something.setter
    def something(self, value):
        """
        Set something.
        """
        # Some value checking here.
        self._something = value
```

I was under the impression that using the property decorators was a reasonable way of implementing properties. Pylint says otherwise. Pylint gives me the following errors:

```
Thing: Too many instance attributes (2/1)
Thing.something: An attribute affected in thing line 10 hide this method
```

If I implement the property the old way, I don't get the same issue.

```
class Thing(object):
    """
    Thing used for stackoverflow example.
    """

    def __init__(self, something):
        """
        Initialize Thing.
        """

        # Set defaults.
        self._something = None

        # Set values using getter/setter methods - this allows for checks.
        self.set_something(something)

    def get_something(self):
        """
        Get something
        """
        return self._something

    def set_something(self, value):
        """
        Set something.
        """
        # Some value checking here.
        self._something = value

    something = property(get_something, set_something)
```

Comment: Ooo ... very interesting.  I think I would consider this a pylint bug (it doesn't seem to recognize that `self.something` is a property and so it's complaining that you're shadowing the `something` method.)

Comment: @mgilson you're right, this is a bug that should be reported on https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/issues